# how to identify the url in tweet is images, video, article or tweet link?

Tags: twitter, nlp, data-analysis

I am collecting tweets. And want to segregate them as per image, videos and articles. Basically tweet segregation based on their media content

Is there any way or logic by which I can recognize that the url in tweet is reffering to some image or video or article ?

Answer (score 4):

For **media**, you can check the [Extended Entities Object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/extended-entities-object). In the object, there is a key named `"type"` - if the tweet you're analyzing has some media, the value can be one of `"photo"`, `"video"`, `"animated_gif"`.

---

For **article**s, you can check the plain [Entities Object](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/entities-object#urls) if the tweet doesn't contains any media when you checked the Extended Entities Object (since media in twitter is URLs too - meaning that if the tweet doesn't contain any media then the URLs contained in the tweet must be a link).

You can get HTML title and description of the link in the Entities Object API, but unfortunately Twitter Cards are not provided by Twitter API - if you need Twitter Card information you should parse the HTML `<head>` element and get the information yourself. For detais see the [Twitter Cards documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/overview/summary.html).